# Trying to automate using selenium for the dynamic classes

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have a

```
Button class = "searchbar__SearchButton-sc-1546roh-3 searchbar__CancelButton-sc-1546roh-4 glEceZ"
```

and trying to return in the browser element using

```
return browser.element('button[class^="searchbar__CancelButton-"]');
```

But I see an error that element can't be found.
can someone help me how can I use the element.

Comment: You should post the full HTML of the `BUTTON`... not just the class portion. You should also post the full error/exception message in case that sheds more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CSS selector spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview), `^` means

```
E[foo^="bar"]   an E element whose foo attribute value begins exactly with the string bar
```

In your case, the class string doesn't start with "searchbar__CancelButton-". You need to change the `^` to `*` to indicate contains.

```
button[class*="searchbar__CancelButton-"]
```